# Get website's source code (content) from Cordova

Tags: cordova, http, httprequest, cordova-plugins, http-get

I was creating a cordova hybrid app when I came across a small problem: I needed to get content from an external website from the app.

To be more clear, I'll explain that in detail: I have a cordova app, I need to get the external websites *source code* and output it inside a `div` tag: exactly like PHP's `file_get_contents`.

I achieved that with jQuery (which I don't want to use) using that code:

```
var request = $.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/',
    type: 'GET',
    crossDomain: true,
    async:false,
    success: function(res) {
        var el = document.createElement('html');
        el.innerHTML = res;
        document.getElementById("anID").innerHTML = el;
    }
});
```

But there are several reasons I don't want to use that solution:

1. The content takes too long to appear
2. It sometimes makes the app crash

So my question is: Can this be made in a more efficient way? Maybe using a plugin that loads content in the background could fix that problem? I need to apply JS to this content so I *don't want to use iframes or inAppBrowser*

**I asked this question after finding nothing from searching on Google and StackOverflow**

---

### **UPDATE:**

I found this plugin that makes HTTP requests but I'm not sure how to use it for this case: https://github.com/wymsee/cordova-HTTP

I am using this code but it's doing nothing:

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", function() {
    window.cordovaHTTP.get("http://www.lycee-tripoli.edu.lb/",
    {},
    {},
    function(response) {
        alert(response.status);
    },
    function(response) {
        alert(response.error);
    });
}, false);
```

This code should alert the response, I copied this from the README.md file. It's actually doing absolutely *nothing*, there's not even an error. Am I doing something wrong??

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You can only extract a certain part of it, and the website service of the website must allow the get method. You can use inappbrowser if you want to open the whole check-it https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/

Comment: I *don't want to use inAppBrowser* as I metioned in the post. Do you know any plugins that could do that?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a little modification -but I don't recommend that- :

```js
var request = $.ajax({
  url: 'https://microsmsm.com/',
  type: 'GET',
  crossDomain: true,
  async: true,
  success: function(res) {
    $("html").html(res);
    //do modifications to html here
  }
});
```

Comment: I would like to *not* use jQuery as I mentioned in the post. Do you know any plugins cabable of doing that efficiently?

Answer (score 0):

You can just do that in vanilla Javascript:

```js
const changeHTMLContent = () => {
    const url = "https://microsmsm.com"
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET", url, true);
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            console.log(xhr.responseText)
            document.open();
            document.write(xhr.responseText)
            document.close();
        }
    }
    xhr.send();
}

changeHTMLContent();
```

Comment: Won't that take the same amount of time it took to jQuery? I would like something that makes it in the background without JS or jQuery. A plugin is made in Java and would definitely be faster.

Comment: No, they are almost identical techniques!

Comment: Sorry, you didn't. I'm looking for a *faster* solution. If it doesn't make it faster, what's the point of using pure JS?

Comment: further read: https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/166273/advantages-of-using-pure-javascript-over-jquery

Comment: Looks great but I still want a plugin solution that can do it in the background and in Java.